# What exactly is the actual coverage probability?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, coverage-probability

I am confused about the difference between the **nominal** and the **actual** [coverage probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_probability).

Say we are trying to estimate the fraction of the current population of the US that has been diagnosed with cancer.  We get a sample (e.g. 10,000 individuals) and then estimate this fraction ($f$) and a confidence interval around it $[a,b]$ with $\alpha$ (confidence level) $=0.95$.

At this point, if I understood things correctly, the nominal coverage probability is $\alpha$, i.e. $0.95$.

But what about the **actual** coverage probability? To me, there is only one true value of $f$, e.g. say $5\%$, and it doesn't make sense to talk about the *actual* probability that $f$ is  within the interval $[a,b]$. It either is or it isn't within $[a,b]$.

What's wrong with this reasoning? And how would one obtain the actual coverage probability in practice?

Comment: Is your question perhaps answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the-mean? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: @whuber. Thanks, I went through that thread, and while interesting (and maybe I am missing something, since I don't fully understand some of the answers), it wasn't clear to me how they addressed the difference between `nonimal` vs `actual` coverage probabilities.

Comment: BTW @whuber, I think I have a good understanding of CIs - the idea being that if we conduct repeated experiments, the proportion of times that the given interval contains the true value of the parameter is its confidence level, but I don't know how to make the leap to nominal vs actual cov. probs.

Comment: That thread discusses the meaning and interpretation of the interval $[a,b]$ covering $f$ and it appears this is exactly the point you are asking about.  Also please see the accepted answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652 (and then browse the other answers).

Comment: The distinction between nominal & actual made in the Wikipedia article is addressed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85666/is-calculating-actual-coverage-probability-the-same-thing-as-calculating-a-cr).