# Is the population parameter more likely to occur closer to the sample statistic?

Tags: confidence-interval, point-estimation

When we use the sample statistic to find a confidence interval, is there any reason to using the sample statistic after that, when we can instead refer to the confidence interval?

For example, let's say I have a sample mean of 50 and have determined a +- 5 interval with 95% confidence.

I could say "The population average is 50, plus-or-minus 5, with 95% confidence"

I could also say "The population average is between 45 and 55, with 95% confidence"

Is the probability of the population parameter occurring uniform across the confidence interval, or, would it be more likely to occur closer to the sample statistic?

The reason I ask, is, it seems to me that if the population parameter is more likely to occur closer to the sample statistic then it's useful to say "50, plus-or-minus 5", while if it's uniform then "between 45 and 55" is simpler.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/what-precisely-is-a-confidence-interval

Comment: So it sounds like what I was thinking of was a credible intergral. Thanks for that

Comment: If the linked questions helped you, please close your question as a duplicate