Is being "a 95% confidence interval" a property of an estimatOR, not a property of an estimatE?
It seems to be agreed upon that "X% confidence interval" means the following:

If I obtain an infinite amount of size $N$ samples from the same distribution and use the same procedure (estimator!) for computing confidence intervals for some fixed parameter $\theta$, then the actual CIs (estimates!) will be different (random), but will contain $\theta$ in X% of the samples.

Another common statement seems to be "X% CI is about the procedure used to obtain the CI, not a particular CI computed from given data" (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6654/328515). Question: does it boil down to the difference between an estimator and an estimate?
I'm thinking that this isn't much different from concepts of unbiasedness and efficiency of estimators, where an "estimator" is any function (procedure) applied to some random variables:

An estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is unbiased if $\mathbb E\hat\theta_n = \theta$, where the expectation is over the distribution of $\hat\theta_n$. The distribution arises because the estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is a function of a random sample containing random variables $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N\}$. As I obtain different samples, I'll get different estimates, but the expected value will be the constant $\theta$. Here the author says "the statistic $\hat\theta_n$, if unbiased, is unbiased in the sense that it will not be too high or too low from the true value on average. (This average is over many samples $X$ of size $N$.)", which seems to support my idea that the notion of "something being true in the limit, as we obtain more and more samples" applies not only to CIs, but to other (point) estimators too. Particular estimates like $\hat\theta=3.141$ can't be biased or unbiased because they aren't random, they're just numbers.
An estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is efficient if its variance is lowest in some class of estimators. Same thing, we can talk about variance because estimators are random variables since they're functions of random samples. Efficiency of a particular estimate makes no sense, since it's just a number.
An estimator is consistent if confidence intervals like $(\hat\theta_n-\varepsilon, \hat\theta_n+\varepsilon)$ have probability 1 as the sample size increases:$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|\hat\theta_n - \theta|<\varepsilon)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(\hat\theta_n-\varepsilon < \theta < \hat\theta_n+\varepsilon)
=1 \quad\forall \varepsilon>0,
$$so $(\hat\theta_n-\varepsilon, \hat\theta_n+\varepsilon)$ is a 100% asymptotic CI for $\theta$ with any $\varepsilon>0$. Again, particular estimates can't be consistent because they aren't random, so there's no probability to compute.

Now, an estimator $(\hat L_n, \hat R_n)$ of a confidence interval has the uncontroversial property:
$$
P(\hat L_n < \theta < \hat R_n) = 1-\alpha
$$
This is fine because the left and right bounds of the interval are random variables.
One can re-write the above probability in terms of the Iverson bracket and the expectation operator:
$$
P(\hat L_n < \theta < \hat R_n) = \mathbb E [\hat L_n < \theta < \hat R_n] = 1-\alpha
$$
In a way, this says that $\widehat{CI}_n(\theta)=[\hat L_n < \theta < \hat R_n]$ is an unbiased estimator of $1-\alpha$. Note that the claim $[\hat L_n < \theta < \hat R_n]=1$ is either true or not, since $\theta$ is fixed. It's a bit strange because it's true even though we don't know $\theta$ in real life. However, we didn't have to know $\theta$ to talk about unbiasedness of $\hat\theta_n$, so it's fine.
In an empirical setting, having computed estimates of the interval's bounds (say, $L_n=-0.3, R_n=-0.1$), a researcher should just claim that $[-0.3 < \theta < -0.1]=1$. As with other estimates, this cannot be verified because we don't know the true underlying distribution. This is why it doesn't make sense to say $P(-0.3 < \theta < -0.1)=1$.

Can I think of confidence intervals like this?

I couldn't understand why someone would need to find an unbiased estimator of $1-\alpha.$

If https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the doesn't answer your question, could you please explain why not?

@whuber, yes, I read all the top [tag:confidence-interval] questions, including this one. None of the answers talk about the "estimator vs estimate" distinction that I see, though. I think that the "X% confidence interval" property is very similar to unbiasedness, consistency and efficiency, for example, because all of them are properties of estimators ("estimating procedures"), not particular estimates. So it makes sense to me that $P(-2<\theta<1)=0.95$ is meaningless for the same reason "-1 is unbiased" is meaningless. In essence, I wanted to ask whether this is correct or not.

@User1865345, me neither, actually, but it seems to follow from definitions of unbiasedness and CI. One thing is that for unbiasedness, the rhs of the definition is the unknown $\theta$ (so it makes sense to estimate it), while here it's the known $1-\alpha$, which is usually incorporated into the CI's bounds. Yeah, that's probably a weird take, indeed

@ForceBru, I still couldn't understand your take with that. But you are right in that it's a matter of estimator and estimate. Estimator has the property that you stated at the beginning. But once you know the realized estimator i.e. the estimate, the only thing you can say is it either covers the unknown $\theta$ or not.

Please search the linked thread for "procedure."

TLDR
I don't believe that the $\alpha \%$ as a coverage probability actually often matters. There is no optimisation that desires this property specifically (the used values are more like a rule of thumb than exact calculated rules).
With a confidence interval people just want to express a range of hypotheses that are not rejected given the data, and not an interval that contains the parameter with a certain probability.

About the definition based on coverage probability

It seems to be agreed upon that "X% confidence interval" means the following: ... will contain θ
in X% of the samples.

The coverage probability is more like a property of a confidence interval (and not a definition).
It is better not to think of it as a definition of the interval. For example, the interval that is $95 \%$ of the time $[-\infty, \infty]$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ otherwise, that interval is a $95 \%$-confidence interval, but that makes little sense in terms of the logic behind the intervals. (The basic logic of constructing a confidence interval)
Confidence intervals are typically more precisely expressing an interval of values for which the observed data makes those hypothetical values pass an $(100-\alpha)\%$ hypothesis test. (Can we reject a null hypothesis with confidence intervals produced via sampling rather than the null hypothesis?)
Technically the above two alineas are not contradictory. Out of any confidence interval, even the silly ones, you can make a hypothesis test. (Confidence interval / p-value duality: don't they use different distributions?)
But a p-value, hypothesis test or confidence interval, should mean something like "a clear distinction in the support of the data for absence versus presence of an effect.". The silly ones that may have the property 'containing the parameter $\alpha \%$ of the time' have not much use.
To think of confidence intervals as merely any interval with the coverage property takes away the purpose of the interval.

estimator vs estimate
Putting all that aside. Yes, the coverage probability property is best understood in terms of the confidence interval as a procedure. So it is more like a property of the estimator instead of a property of the estimate.
For example, the earlier mentioned $[-\infty, \infty]$ interval obviously contains the parameter with $100\%$ certainty.
(Why does a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) not imply a 95% chance of containing the mean?)

Confidence interval is a special case of the more general set estimator which is a map $C$ from the sample space $\mathscr X$ to the collection of sets $\mathcal C$ such that $\mathbf x\mapsto \mathbb I_{C(\mathbf x)}(\theta) $ is measurable for all $\theta\in\Theta.$ The coverage $c_\theta:=\mathsf E_\theta\{I_{C(\mathbf x)}(\theta)\}=\mathsf P_\theta\{C(\mathbf X)\ni\theta \}.$
$C(\mathbf X) $ is an $(1-\alpha)$ confidence set if $$\inf_{\theta\in\Theta} c_\theta\geq 1-\alpha.\tag 1\label 1$$
$C(\mathbf X) $ is an estimator. $\eqref 1$ confers on the estimator the frequentist interpretation that OP stated at the very beginning. However, once realized, $C(\mathbf x) $  either will cover $\theta$ or won't cover $\theta$  with probability $0$ or $1.$

However, once realized, $C(\mathbf x) $  either will cover $\theta$ or won't cover $\theta$  with probability $0$ or $1.$. Say we consider the 95% confidence interval for the true speed of light in vacuum which is for some experiment between 299647.641 km/sec and 299864.789 km/sec. So now that we realised this interval, it is definite and we can tell whether the probability is 0 or 1?

Let me quote it from C&B sec. $9.2$ '"Formally, the interval $[.262, 1.184]$ is one of the realized values of the random interval... and since the parameter $\lambda$ does not move, $\lambda$ is in the realized interval $[.262, 1.184]$  with probability either $0$ or $1.$" @SextusEmpiricus

Yes the parameter is either in the interval or not in the interval. But in the same way the unknown result of a coin flip is either heads or tails. So when a coin flip has been realised, but is unknown, we say that it's probability is either 0 or 1 to be heads, instead of the usual $p$ probabability?

Sextus, you might be convoluting two different problems: say I flip a coin with probability of heads being $p.$ And I didn't report you about the realized toss. You would say either heads would occur with probability $\Pr[\text{heads}]=p$ or not with probability $1-p.$ Whereas in the confidence interval case, the interval is random and not the parameter $\theta.$ So, once the observation is realized, we have $C(\mathbf x) . $ The probability that it includes $\theta$ is $\Pr[\theta\in C(\mathbf x) ]=1$ or $0$ depending on its inclusion.

I am convoluting the problems on purpose, because they are the same. Once an event/observation has been realized doesn't stop us from making probability statements.

Hm. I have to go with C&B here @SextusEmpiricus.

@SextusEmpiricus Regarding your coin tossing example, if the coin and coin flipping procedure is assumed fair then, prior to the flip, the probability of heads is 0.5. If the  coin is tossed but kept hidden from all then, from a frequentist perspective, it is reasonable to say there is 50% confidence that that toss shows heads, since that particular toss is the outcome of a procedure that shows heads 50% of the time.

An interesting difference in the comparison is the part that is unknown. With the coinflip it is the variable outcome that's still unknown and we apply 'probability' to it. In the confidence interval it's the variable outcome that has become known, but only the parameter (which can be fixed in most practical situations) is unknown. In a way we can still apply probability to it, like Bayesian techniques do, but it is only untractable if you do not have an objective prior. That's why some people dislike Bayesian techniques, but I wouldn't say that probability either 0 or 1 is a solution instead.
