# Newbie: Difference between the meaning for the data analysis: proportion of correct responses and probability of correct responses

Tags: probability, distributions, proportion

Very newbie, sorry if the question seems to be not very smart...

If proportion of correct respones is defined as

Number of hits + Number of correct rejections / Number of trials

Is the probability of correct responses  -> probability of hits + probability of correct rejections / probability of all trials happening

-> Does the difference lie in the fact, that the **probability** uses distributions with the data of **proportions**? Is therefore probability of correct more important for data analysis?

-> Or is prob. and prop. the same thing?

-> And what does then "accuracy" mean? Prob. or prop.?

Comment: You might want to refer to this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/whats-the-difference-between-a-probability-and-a-proportion

Comment: You might want to read this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/whats-the-difference-between-a-probability-and-a-proportion

Comment: @Pitouille Yes, thank you

Comment: @Pitouille Indeed, it clarified for me the difference. Thanks. 
But what do we call then accuracy? proportion or the probability of correct responses?

Comment: Here is a list of common terminology related to this issue (see the list at the right of the page): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between probability and proportion is that a proportion is over a finite number of given trials, while a probability is theoretical. The two are related in that if the probability of a miss is 5%, then over a larger and larger sample the miss count will come closer and closer to 5%.
A proportion computed over a large sample will give you a fair idea of the associated probability, a phenomenon that can be quantified by the computation of a [Confidence Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

Accuracy in your context means the probability to make the **correct** decision (whatever this decision has to be, accept or reject). The "proportion" version of it being given by the formula (number of correct decisions made) / (total number of trials). Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_binary_classification

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Comment: @jorg You're welcome! Feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.